How can I show and hide Like/Unlike buttons using Javascript in my Web app?
I'm doing online course CS50W by Harvard and building a web app similar to twitter.
When user sees a post I need to show the user Like or Unlike button depending on user liked it or not. There's also a counter showing how many users liked the post so far. I am able to update the counter if the user liked or unliked the post, but I'm having problem with the code showing or hiding the buttons.
Here's my code:
models.py
class Post(models.Model):
    """ Model representing a post. """
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    content = models.TextField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    no_of_likes = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"Post {self.id} by {self.user.username} on {self.timestamp}"
    
class Like(models.Model):
    """ Model representing a like. """
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.user} likes {self.post}"

urls.py
path("", views.index, name="index"),
path("like/<int:post_id>", views.like, name="like"),
path("unlike/<int:post_id>", views.unlike, name="unlike"),

views.py
def index(request):
    """ Home page. """
    posts = Post.objects.all().order_by('-timestamp')
    paginator = Paginator(posts, 5)
    page_number = request.GET.get('page')
    page_obj = paginator.get_page(page_number)
    likes = Like.objects.all()  
    
    # Make a list of liked posts.
    liked_posts = []
    try:
        for like in likes:
            if like.user.id == request.user.id:
                liked_posts.append(like.post.id)
    except:
        liked_posts = []

    return render(request, "network/index.html", {
        "posts": posts,
        "page_obj": page_obj,
        "likes": likes,
        "liked_posts": liked_posts,             
    })

@login_required
def like(request, post_id):
   
    post = Post.objects.get(pk=post_id)
    user = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
    like = Like.objects.create(user=user, post=post)
    like.save()

    # Update no of likes.
    post.no_of_likes = Like.objects.filter(post=post).count()
    post.save()
    return JsonResponse({"message": "successfully liked", "no_of_likes": post.no_of_likes})

@login_required   
def unlike(request, post_id):
    
    post = Post.objects.get(pk=post_id)
    user = User.objects.get(pk=request.user.id)
    like = Like.objects.filter(user=user, post=post)
    like.delete()

    # Update no of likes.
    post.no_of_likes = Like.objects.filter(post=post).count()
    post.save()
    return JsonResponse({"message": "successfully unliked", "no_of_likes": post.no_of_likes})

index.html with Javascript
{% if post.id not in liked_posts %}
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="like{{ post.id }}" onclick="like('{{ post.id         }}')">Like</button>
{% else %}
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="unlike{{ post.id }}"onclick="unlike('{{ post.id }}')">Unlike</button>
{% endif %}

function like(id) {
        fetch(`/like/${id}`, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "X-CSRFToken": "{{ csrf_token }}",
            },
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            document.querySelector(".no-of-likes").innerHTML = data.no_of_likes + " likes";
        })
        .then(() => {
            document.getElementById("unlike" + id).style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("like" + id).style.display = "none";
        });
    }

function unlike(id) {
        fetch(`/unlike/${id}`, {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
                "Content-Type": "application/json",
                "X-CSRFToken": "{{ csrf_token }}",
            },
        })
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => {
            document.querySelector(".no-of-likes").innerHTML = data.no_of_likes + " likes";
        })
        .then(() => {
            document.getElementById("unlike" + id).style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("like" + id).style.display = "block";
        });
    }   

I can update the counter without refreshing the page, but it's not the same with buttons.
This is what happening:
--> When I click Like button counter updates. I have to refresh the page to change button to Unlike. As per the specification this needs to be done asynchronously (assuming with the help of Javascript!) without reloading the page.
--> And it's same with Unlike button too. When I click it counter updates but I have to reload the page to change the button to Like.
I want to change the buttons without reloading the page. Tried placing code blocks at different places, tried using 'if else' conditions but I'm still stuck here. Any help is appreciated!
Sorry for the messy Javascript code, newbie here.

Why not just make one button, instead of two with one you hide. You here only generate one button, because the template is rendered at the server side.

That is because you are only rendering one button. Add the two, one you hide, the other you show:
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="like{{ post.id }}" onclick="like('{{ post.id }}')" style="display: {% if post.id not in liked_posts %}block{% else %}none{% endif %};">Like</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="unlike{{ post.id }}" onclick="unlike('{{ post.id }}')" style="display: {% if post.id in liked_posts %}block{% else %}none{% endif %};">Unlike</button>
But I don't see why you need to use two buttons in the first place: just use one button that you use both for liking and unliking depending on the context.


Note: Please don't store aggregates in the model: determine aggregates when needed: storing aggregates in the model makes updating and keeping data in sync harder. You can use .annotate(…) [Django-doc] to generate counts, sums, etc. per object when needed.


Your code is working, Thank you. Though I tried to change the code as you suggested! I created one button and wrote a function toggleLike(postId) to change .innerText to Like or Unlike using 'if else' conditions. That part is working fine. But when I refresh the page the buttons are showing Like only. I tried to change the buttons with document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {// Logic here} but not having any success! Can you please give me any suggestions regarding how to fix it. Cheers!

@srikk407: is it possible to ask a new question with the new state of the view(s) and template?

I haven't changed 'views.py' that much only 'html button and javascript code'. Here's the link to my new code:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78456711/how-to-render-right-buttons-like-or-unlike-in-a-post-based-on-users-choice-us
